# Using a variable in $smarty.get?

Tags: smarty

I need to retrieve the `$_GET` data from the URL in a smarty .tpl file. The specific `$_GET` I need to retrieve is in a loop. I need to use the example below but with a variable for `page`.

```
{* display value of page from URL ($_GET) http://www.example.com/index.php?page=foo *}
{$smarty.get.page}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{assign var="foo" value="assign whatever you want"}
{$smarty.get.$foo}
```